# Difference between @list.tasks and @list.tasks.all in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm building a simple todo list app where each list can contain many tasks .

list.rb

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :tasks   
end
```

task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :list
 attr_accessible :description,:completed
 validates :description, presence: true
 validates :list, presence: true
end
```

The show action of my ListsController :
Lists#show

```
 def show
  @list = List.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @task =@list.tasks.build
 end
```

Now in my lists/show.html.erb where I show all tasks under that particular list :

```
<% raise @list.tasks.all.inspect %>
```

This gives output `[]` .   But when I change the show.html.erb like so :

```
<% raise @list.tasks.inspect %>
```

This gives output `[#<Task id: nil, description: nil, list_id: 13, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, completed: nil>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally build will just create a record in the collection and it is not stored to the database.

So in this case, the data records from database has been retrieved. Since you have no records stored yet, you get an empty set.

```
<% raise @list.tasks.all.inspect %>
# []
```

In this case,

```
 @task =@list.tasks.build  # create a empty record with list_id in the collection tasks
 #<Task id: nil, description: nil, list_id: 13, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, completed: nil>

<% raise @list.tasks.inspect %> # Get data from collection. Collection holds database records + recently built records.
 [#<Task id: nil, description: nil, list_id: 13, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, completed: nil>]
```

If you want to save you recent build to database then do the following.

```
@list.save # it will commit the records built to database
```

Now if you do **@list.tasks.all.inspect** you will get all records from database.

```
@list.tasks.all.inspect
[#<Task id: 1, description: nil, list_id: 13, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, completed: nil>]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@list.tasks` it returns tasks belonging to this list and everything is as expected

`.all` is deprecated method [all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/all/class) which is just alias for calling `find(:all)`.

Thus, in `@list.tasks.all` you get `@list.tasks.find(:all)` which returns empty enumerable.

Comment: So,does it mean that the `find(:all)` method returns only the records which have been saved ?

Comment: no, it tries to find hash with key :all. :all is not a method here. Also having list of tasks, why would you want to call all on that list?

Answer (score 0):

@list.tasks is an ActiveRelation and won't actually query the db unless it has to (like when it has to write it to the screen during an irb session.

You can verify this yourself by typing: list.tasks.class within a rails console

whereas @list.tasks.all will explicitly tell the ActiveRelation to perform the query.

You can do some reading on "lazy evaluation" for more information

Comment: I just tried List.find(6).tasks.class in the console and it did query the database ..and so did List.find(6).tasks.all.class ..